# WP REST API, query total posts in a category

Tags: posts, rest-api

I have just started playing with the WP REST API and found that when querying posts that there is a limit of 10 post per page unless specified. What I would like to know if is is possible to return the total number of post in a category though meta data or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

To just know the number of posts in a category, its endpoint returns that number straightforward, in example:

```
curl http://wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/24
```

In the resource returned, the `count` field says: 486

Which is the same number the metadata says about the total number of posts, if you request the posts in that category, rather than the category itself:

```
curl -I http://wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=24
```

You can read the header `X-WP-Total: 486`.

REST API of WordPress follows best practices in use today for APIs, among others, return metadata about a request in the headers, plus links to traverse the collection if it is possible.

There is no need to wait for an array of posts of length === 0 in order to know there are no more pages of posts.

Actually, the rest API return in headers, metadata about the number of pages and total of posts available to this same endpoint/filter.

For example, take the API of wired.com:

```
curl -I http://wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/
```

It returns three headers relevant to this question:

```
Link: <http://www.wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=2>; rel="next"
X-WP-TotalPages: 18067
X-WP-Total: 180664
```

As you can see, the results are consistent enough to know if you need to retrieve more posts or you have reached the end of the listing. You have X-WP-Total showing total of resources for this endpoint, X-WP-TotalPages showing number of pages with the same number of posts (default is 10, but you can request more with query argument `per_page`).

And the Link header gives you even more information which you can use to traverse without even storing the total number of posts before requesting more.

For example: `$ curl -I http://www.wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=18067`
Gives you this Link header:

```
Link: <http://www.wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=18066>; rel="prev"
```

(No `next` link, just as first page has not `prev` link).

And an intermediate page: `$ curl -I http://www.wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=2`
Gives you next and prev links:

```
Link: <http://www.wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1>; rel="prev", <http://www.wired.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=3>; rel="next"
```

I'd suspect the number of posts REST API can return is more related to server capabilities, since I've being able to return `per_page=100` without any trouble.

Comment: to be able to collect the number of tickets we can get it from the header headers ['x-wp-total']

Answer (score -1):

A bit late to the party but in case someone trying to find a solution to do such thing with WP REST API even v2, I have to say **YOU CANNOT**.
I've spent hours on searching through Google and WordPress or the library official docs but unfortunately came up with nothing.

So I tried getting posts with increasing page number until the returned **JSON array length** becomes **0** which means there's **no more page with posts** on the category, and stopped increasing the page number.

Hope it helps somebody.